# how to use categories values at homepage in opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I would like to use the values of name, description, url and image for each product category in my opencart 2 site. I've seen some examples but none is working, can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Categories have SEO URL's and images and descriptions, but their display is controlled the template.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I want to feed a list dynamically in my homepage with those values of each category: name, description, SEO url and image, I tried copying part of the Categories controller and pasting it in the home controller and modifying the view but it's not working, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to any controller and run. If you want to get categories in homepage, open the file catalog/conlroller/common/home.php and place this code in index() method.

```
// to get all categories
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories();
print_r($categories);
```